# vb.net dynamically created form name with variable

Tags: vb.net, forms, datagridview, dynamically-generated

I have this peace of code but I am looking for a way to simplify it with the use of dynamically created names. I have looked into reflection and activator.createinstance methods but can't find a good example.

```
Private Sub ChangeToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ChangeToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim DbNr As Integer = Strings.Right(DataGridName.Name, 1)
    If DataGridName.Name = Dgv_1.Name Then
        Dim Obj As New RightClickMenuDgv_1("Change", ValueMaster, ValueIdDgv(DbNr))
        If Obj.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            RefreshDataGrids("Change")
        End If
    ElseIf DataGridName.Name = Dgv_2.Name Then
        Dim Obj As New RightClickMenuDgv_2("Change", ValueMaster, ValueIdDgv(DbNr))
        If Obj.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            RefreshDataGrids("Change")
        End If
    ElseIf DataGridName.Name = Dgv_3.Name Then
        Dim Obj As New RightClickMenuDgv_3("Change", ValueMaster, ValueIdDgv(DbNr))
        If Obj.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            RefreshDataGrids("Change")
        End If
    ElseIf DataGridName.Name = Dgv_4.Name Then
        Dim Obj As New RightClickMenuDgv_4("Change", ValueMaster, ValueIdDgv(DbNr))
        If Obj.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            RefreshDataGrids("Change")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

So I am looking for something like this:

```
Private Sub ChangeToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ChangeToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim DbNr As Integer = Strings.Right(DataGridName.Name, 1)
    Dim Obj As New RightClickMenuDgv_(DbNr)("Change", ValueMaster, ValueIdDgv(DbNr))
    If Obj.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        RefreshDataGrids("Change")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there's no point comparing properties of objects when you can compare objects, i.e. don't do this:

```
If DataGridName.Name = Dgv_1.Name Then
```

but rather do this:

```
If DataGridName Is Dgv_1 Then
```

As for your question, what you're asking for isn't really possible. If you want to invoke a constructor like that then you MUST specify a data type.  There are ways to simplify your code somewhat though.  E.g.

```
Dim grids = {Dgv_1, Dgv_2, Dgv_3, Dgv_4}
Dim gridNumber = Array.IndexOf(grids, DataGridName) + 1
Dim dialogue As Form

Select Case gridNumber
    Case 1:
        dialogue = New RightClickMenuDgv_1("Change", ValueMaster, ValueIdDgv(gridNumber))
    Case 2:
        dialogue = New RightClickMenuDgv_2("Change", ValueMaster, ValueIdDgv(gridNumber))
    Case 3:
        dialogue = New RightClickMenuDgv_3("Change", ValueMaster, ValueIdDgv(gridNumber))
    Case 4:
        dialogue = New RightClickMenuDgv_4("Change", ValueMaster, ValueIdDgv(gridNumber))
End Select

If dialogue.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
    RefreshDataGrids("Change")
End If
```

There's no way to get around having four separate lines for creating the four separate dialogue types though, unless you want to resort to using Reflection, which seems silly to save half a dozen lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually came up with the following idea:

```
Private Sub ToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NewToolStripMenuItem.Click, ChangeToolStripMenuItem.Click, DeleteToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim Action As String = sender.name.ToString.Split("ToolStripMenuItem")(0)
    Dim DbNr As Integer = Strings.Right(DataGridName.Name, 1)
    CallByName(Me, $"ShowForm{DbNr}", CallType.Method, Action, ValueMaster, ValueIdDgv(DbNr))
End Sub


Public Sub ShowForm1(ByVal action As String, ByVal primary As String, ByVal secondary As String)
    Dim Obj As New RightClickMenuForm1(action, primary, secondary)
    If Obj.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        RefreshDataGrids(action)
    End If
End Sub
```

In the end it is still not what I was looking for but this way I can group 3 actions together for one form. Still have to call different forms but that's ok because I can give them a more meaningful name.